# Using itertools combination and permutation functions to count for repeated elements

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations, permutation

I need to use itertools module to find the total number of permutations of an n element sequence of `"O"`s and `"X"`s. (n will be a known constant, but please give your answer for n=8). For example, if I was to enter 3, it should output:

```
OOO
OOX
OXO
XOO
OXX
XXO
XOX
XXX
```

not necessarily in that order. I am currently using itertools and its combinations/permutations/combinations_with_replacement functions to do this, but it can't seem to figure out that if I give it an array with multiple elements that are the same, that they are the same. To find combinations, I am great, I can currently just do:

```py
comb = combinations_with_replacement(["O", "X"], 8)
```

which outputs

```
('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X')
```

However, when I use the permutations function, it differentiates between equal elements, making there be 8 factorial times 9 = 40320 times 9 output tuples, when there should only be 2^8=256 outputs. Can someone please help?

Thanks!

---

EDIT: I also need to actually generate the permutations. NOT JUST FIND THE TOTAL NUMBER OF THEM.

Comment: So you found a solution with ```combination_with_replacement()``` you just want to know why ```permutation``` is giving you this result?

Comment: No, I still want different permutations, not combinations. For example, right now, it is thinking ["O", "O","O", "O","O", "O","O", "O"] is the same as ["O", "O","O", "O","O", "O","O", "O"], which is obvious wrong. It is differentiating "O" from "O", which is why it is happening. However, I still want to differentiate ["X", "O","O", "O","O", "O","O", "O"] from ["O", "X","O", "O","O", "O","O", "O"]. I don't ONLY want combinations, which would only give me 9 outputs. So I have found the start of a solution, but I still need help on _completing_ it

Comment: What's wrong with `2**n`?

Comment: Nothing's wrong...it just isn't giving it.

Comment: Isn't giving what?

Comment: It was giving me way more than just 2**n...Oh, I think you misunderstood what my question is. I want my program to generate all the permutations, not just count how many there are.

Comment: I have one more question: if I want to quickly _make_ all permutations of ["X", "O","O", "O","O", "O","O", "O"], how would I find it?

Comment: Your question says "count" and "find the total number".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` with the `repeat` parameter to get the output you want:

```
for xos in itertools.product('OX', repeat=3):
    print(xos)
```

Gives:

```
('O', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'X')
```

For `repeat=8`, you'll get 256 results:

```
('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O')
('X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X')
```

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely try this out.

Comment: I have one more question: if I want to quickly _make_ all permutations of ["X", "O","O", "O","O", "O","O", "O"], how would I find it?

Comment: @BobRobert: Since there's only one "X", I'd do `["O"*i + "X" + "O"*(8-i) for i in range(8)]` (or the equivalent with tuples/lists, if that's important).

Comment: I just realized this is simpler than I thought. I actually just needed to check whether it was one of those, and I can use the .count() function to check that. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `itertools.product(...)` instead:

```py
from itertools import product

Res=list(product(["o", "x"], repeat=8))
```

Comment: I have one more question: if I want to quickly _make_ all permutations of ["X", "O","O", "O","O", "O","O", "O"], how would I find it?